# sprinkledata: How to connect using Salesforce connector

Tags: api, external-services

This might be very specific to tool `sprinkledata`. But I have tried everything.

[image]

Only these data needs to be filled in and I tried everything.
On 
`Server Location*` : I tried `Instance Name`, `test`, `whole url`
`Password` : I tried password/ Password + Security Token
`Security Token` : `Tried Security Token`

But it always returns this error message:

`Failed: unable to login code is 500 error message <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>INVALID_LOGIN</faultcode><faultstring>INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.</faultstring><detail><sf:LoginFault xsi:type="sf:LoginFault"><sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_LOGIN</sf:exceptionCode><sf:exceptionMessage>Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.</sf:exceptionMessage></sf:LoginFault></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>`

If anyone has worked with `sprinkledata` can you please share what info needs to go in these fields.

**I am still able to login normally via browser with the password.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under the login history of your user to make sure you can see the error.

User locked out means you may have to reset it.

The other issue could be the connector is making a SOAP login call to the Production instead of Sandbox and you are providing sandbox credentials.

Comment: no, thats the first thing I checked, requests are not even going there. No login history tracked.

Comment: That answers it. It simply means it is going to sandbox instead of PROD or vice versa

Comment: But prod does not even have this user. And there is no way to add a URL, stating where should it go, its just taking server url.

Comment: How does sprinkle data ensure that it is going to sandbox or prod? I would try in the server url using login.salesforce.com if PROD or test.salesforce.com if Sandbox

Comment: This was the issue,  actually this tool always connects to prod whatevr we give in server location.  May be a bug in this tool.